# How to avoid double click on different button?

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

My problem is not a double click on same button but on 2 buttons.

User make a double click on a button.

- The first click is detected by a first button
- the controller do the action
- the UI is refreshed, another button is display at same position
- the second click is catched by the second button
  => user don't want click on the second button

How can I avoid this ?

I have tested :

- To disable all UI buttons during action
  but if action is really quick, buttons are enable before the second click
- To not put 2 buttons on same place in the UI
  not always possible and with responsive UI it's not possible to manage all cases
- To add a global timestamp on click, and test during the second click if we have 500ms

  ```
              _click: function(args)
              {
                  // to avoid double click user need wait 500ms between each click
                  if(window.paperbutton_timestamp)
                  {
                      var diff = new Date() - window.paperbutton_timestamp;                            
                      if(diff < 500)
                      {
                          window.paperbutton_timestamp = new Date();                        
                          return;
                      }
                  }
                  window.paperbutton_timestamp = new Date();                        

                  if(scope.click)
                  {
                      scope.click(args);
                  }
              },
  ```

Ok it does the job.

Now my problem is I have many protractor end to end tests, with more 2000 clicks. 
Some protractor click are done in less 500ms.

Which solution can I have ?
 1. Add a wait after each click
 (more 2000 wait to add manually)
 2. Set the 500ms in a global variable and override this value to 0ms
 how to override on each test and each page refresh ?
 3. Override protractor click ?
  Seam is the better solution but I don't know how to do this.

- Do you have another better idea :) ?

Comment: You have tagged the question with [tag:angular], but that code does not seem to be the usual Typescript from a Component

Comment: Animate the switch from one to the second button for like 300ms, making it unclickable during this time, and make your timeout 300ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you write a custom function for protractor click:

```
protractor.ElementFinder.prototype.waitClick = function(wait){
  browser.sleep(wait);
  this.click();
};

describe('Tests', function() {
  element.all(by.css('#testElements')).get(0).waitClick(1000)
});
```

Since, overriding the default click function is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually solved using good old human-computer interaction. Try using a style of button that visually reacts to hover, mousedown and mouseup events. This is usually enough to the user understand that a double click is not necessary. Stackoverflow itself has an awesome example:

Iddle button:

[image]

Hover button:

[image]

Mousedown button:

[image]

Mouseup button:

[image]

But if you really wish to prevent undesired clicks, maybe the best approach would be to disable buttons during actions and when you are about to re-enable then, put this action in a timeout, so the disabled buttons will last a little longer.

### Another suggestion

You could implement a global function to spawn an invisible `div` covering the whole screen when required. This would prevent everything onscreen from working.

```
<div style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100vw; height:100vh; z-index: 10000"></div>
```

Put it in your layout file, usually `app.component.html`, and implement a `*ngIf` for it show up only when necessary. Also, its `z-index` should be greater than the `z-index` of any other element in your whole app.

Comment: Thanks, but my user don't understang that double click is not necessary on web. They double click every where. The solution to add a timer to enable buttons is the correct solution. But we need implement this mecanism everywhere. I searched a global solution to avoid developper ommit :) Thanks Pedro

Comment: I see. Knowing your user is really important. I added a new suggestion now, so mind my edit. :)

Comment: Thanks Pedro, but with this solution I always have the problem on my e2e tests wich can't click if there is this covering div. It's approximatively the same solution I have proposed. I search to override protractor click, I see a post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082069/how-do-i-override-protractors-click-method-in-protractor-3-and-higher but without solution :)

Answer (score 1):

have you consider Using *NgIf for both the buttons 
**

```
<button *NgIf="oneActive" (click)="oneActive=false;callfunction()">one</button>
<button *NgIf="!oneActive" (click)="oneActive=true;callfunction2()">two</button>
```

**

Comment: yes it's a part of the solution with [disable]="window.viewDisable" and set a 500ms timeout after each action to set window.viewDisable = false. Need be global because button are not necessary in the same scope