# How to override click on webElement

Tags: protractor

For some reasons ([How to avoid double click on different button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849127/how-to-avoid-double-click-on-different-button/)) I need add a 300ms sleep on each click.

There is a way to do this ?

I prefer a generic method instead add a sleep after each click on all e2e test files

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest to disable double-click protection for testing purposes, as long as protractor test can't afford such a mistake. The 300 ms delay may have negative impact by increasing overall time spent on running tests.

Though, if you still want the delay - you can create your own click method

```
protractor.ElementFinder.prototype.customClick = function() {
  browser.sleep(300);
  this.click();
};
```

P.S. Overriding native `click` method is not a good idea, because eventually you may need a simple click event without a delay.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I really think it will help me.